# Sufficient statistic under transformation

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I just read a weird question when I'm learning sufficient statistic myself. It says whether the sufficient statistic of variance and standard deviation are the same under normal distribution with known $\mu$.

The first idea comes like, they are the same since if the statistic of variance is sufficient, then it must be sufficient for the square root. And I think factorisation theorem can show this as well.

However, I just finish the learning about unbiased estimator. It says unbiasedness is not preserved under transformation. Like sample variance is unbiased while sample standard deviation is biased. Quite confused if the transformation will affect the sufficient statistic.
The question may be stupid since I just start to learn statistic. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your question about sufficiency or unbiasedness? Please clarify!

Comment: @kjetil I think the question is about a confusion about the difference between sufficiency and biasedness.

Answer (score 1):

You seem confused about the concepts of sufficiency and unbiasedness. To be clear: **unbiasedness plays no part in the definition of sufficiency**. The reason is simple: If $T$ is sufficient for some parameter $\theta$ indexing a distribution family, then so is also $T/10, 10T, 1000T$ and a lot of other one-to-one functions of $T$. Al those functions cannot be unbiased at the same time (as estimators of $\theta$ or of some function of $\theta$.) When you are clear about this you can think again, starting afresh, on your first paragraph question.